# Date wise update records from multiple tables

Tags: sql-server, database

My requirement is like this

I have 3 tables table 1, table 2 and table 3 with address number common between all 3 tables

table 1 has address number as primary key hence only one record will be there for each address number. table 2 and table 3 has multiple records for each address number

I need to udapte the section column in table 3 based on the effective date from table 2 for each address number fetched from table 1.

Hence we need to fetch the address number from table 1, pass it to table 2 and filter the number of records for that address number. After fitlering i have to fetch the least effective date if there are more than one record in the table 2. Then pass the address number and the effective date as >= Effective date to the table 3 and filter the records for address number with dates greater than or equal to the effective date. Passs the section value from the table 2 to section column of all the filtered records of table 3.

**Example:
Table structure:**

**Table 1: (one column - address number)**
Address number - 100

Fetch the address number from table 1  - 100

**Table 2:  (3 columns - adddress number, section, Effective date)**
Address number - 100
Section -  A
Effective date - 1/1/2014

Address number - 100
Section - B
Effective date - 1/1/2015

In table 2 you have 2 records as shown above for address number 100 with section A and B and with different dates.

From these 2 records select the least effective date (1/1/2014 is the least effective date). Pass the Address number as - 100 and Date as >= 1/1/2014 to Table 3 (>= should be hardcoded)

**Table 3:  (3 columns - adddress number, section, date)**

Address number - 100
Section -
Date 2/2/2014

Address number - 100
Section - 
Date - 2/2/2015

Address number - 100
Section - 
Date 3/3/2015

Table 3 consists of 3 records for address number 100 with different dates and no values for Section column

we pass the Address number and >= Effective date to the table 3 and filter the records. As per the above example all 3 records are >= 1/1/2014. Now pass the Section value of 1/1/2014 (value = A) from Table 2 to Table 3 for all 3 records.

Next pass the second least effective date from Table 2  (1/1/2015). Pass the address number and date as >= 1/1/2015. as per the above example 2 records will be filtered. 2/2/2015 and 3/3/2015. Pass the Section value of 1/1/2015 (section B) to 2/2/2015 and 3/3/2015 record

**Expected Result in Table 3**

**Table 3:**

Address number - 100
Section - A
Date 2/2/2014

Address number - 100
Section - B
Date 2/2/2015

Address number - 100
Section - B
date 3/3/2015

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/ As posted there simply isn't enough information to know what you are trying to do.

Comment: Post what you have so far